# How to upload file from javascript to php server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to upload image or other file from javascript to php server ???
i am working on php api how to send and receive 
please help me
i am getting josn data using

```
$login = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

i want to upload image using js and receive using php and upload to server disk
Here is my login.php file

```
  <?php
session_start();
//server accpet response in forllowing format 
//{"username":"administrator","password":"administrator","remind":"on"}
// iuncluding function file
require_once "../includes/system.php";
    if(isset($_COOKIE['COOKIE_KEEP_ME_NAME1shpingcart'])){
            $_SESSION['login_usershoping'] =  $_COOKIE['COOKIE_KEEP_ME_NAME1shpingcart'];
        }   
   if(isset($_SESSION['login_usershoping'])){
    $success['alreadylogin'] = "true";
    echo $successlogin = malik_encode($success );
    die();
}
// get value
$login = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if(empty($login)){
        $error['error'] = "Username & password never be empty";
        echo $errorlogin = malik_encode($error );
        die();
    }
//decode and convert into assos array by using custom function
$login_decode = malik_decode($login,true);
    $username =  $login_decode['username'];
    $password =  $login_decode['password'];
    $remind = $login_decode['remind'];

    $db = malik_database_connection();
    $connected = null;   
    $username = $db->quote($username);
        $select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username");
        if($select->rowCount() > 0){
            $user = $select->fetch();
            $ban = $user['ban'];
              if($ban === 'yes'){
                 $error['error'] = "Your account is banned by our admistrator";
                 echo $banerror = malik_encode($error );
              }         
            if (password_verify($password, $user["password"])){
                if(isset($remind) && $remind === 'on'){
                //generate for storing cookies
                setcookie('COOKIE_KEEP_ME_NAME1shpingcart',$user['salts'] ,time() + (86400 * 30 * 12), '/',false,true);
                //generate for storing cookies
                setcookie('COOKIE_KEEP_ME_NAME2',malik_ramdomstring_generator(60) ,time() + (86400 * 30 * 12), '/',false,true);
                //generate for storing cookies
                setcookie('COOKIE_KEEP_ME_NAME3',malik_ramdomstring_generator(50) ,time() + (86400 * 30 * 12), '/',false,true);
                }   
                $se= $_SESSION['login_usershoping'] =  $user['salts'];
                 $success['success'] = "true";
                 echo $loginsuccess = malik_encode($success );
                exit();

            }else {
                $connected = false;
            }
            }else{
            $connected = false;
        }
           if ($connected === false): 
           $error['error'] = "Username and password wrong";
            echo $loginerror = malik_encode($error );
         $connected = null; 
       endif;
```

Comment: It does not seem that you really know what you are doing here.
Have you used `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_FILES`  before ?
You should look up those, and please use PDO fro database connections...

Comment: I use PDO for db connection

Comment: My question is how to send file format js to phone and receive

Comment: http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/ajax-file-upload-php-jquery-tutorial/

Comment: My bad about PDO, have you considered prepared statements ?
`$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?");`
 then  `if(!$q->execute([$id])){ die('Error...'); }`
then .. `$results = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Sorry not helpfull i want upload image or other file using javascript and receive form php like api  like login user able to write android apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152312/discussion-between-kristian-hareland-and-malik-umer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upload.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="uploadform">
            <input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
            <button type="submit">
                Upload!
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $("form#uploadform").submit(function () {
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/upload_file.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                },
                error:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

upload_file.php:

```
/*
 * Do your authentication logic here, log in user, etc.
 */

//Fist, check if we have any file sent to the script:
$file = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : NULL;


//It seems we have a file?
$tmpfile = $file['tmp_name'];
//Find the file extension:
$fileparts = explode('.', $file['name']);

//Apply the extension, usually the last item in the parts array:
$fileExtension = $fileparts[count($fileparts) - 1];

//Make a filename:
$filename = md5($file['name']);

//add file extension to the filename:
$filename .= '.' . $fileExtension;

//Save to current directory:
$saveto = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

//Move file:
move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $saveto);

///If we ever get here, the file has been uploaded, saved and moved to the permanent location
print 'File saved to: ' . $saveto;
```